# entry point mkl_blas_dgem2vu could not be located

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder

I'm running Anaconda/Spyder and I keep getting the Intel Math Library error shown in the picture:

[image: Error]

It seems like an entry point for mkl_blas_dgem2vu is missing (whatever that is).

I was still able to run Spyder until I tried updating everything. After updating Spyder doesn't start after receiving this error.

I stuck and can't do anything right now.

Thanks.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7357) bug report. It could help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I already found that post and it solved part of my problem.

Comment: I guess that's all part of the DLL hell. Anaconda helped me, see here https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10672 (Anaconda fixed that, unless other ISVs are responsible for the bad behaviour of dropping dll in C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 2):

I already found that post and it solved part of my problem.

First part of problem is that different a version of the MKL library was in the system32 & SYSWOW64 directories. It was loaded by another application. Anaconda was using those libraries instead of the one installed for Anaconda. I eliminated the other versions of the MKL libraries and reinstalled Anaconda. I tried without re-installing and it didn't work.

The 2nd problem was solved with that post you suggested that I found on my own. It seems like Spyder or Ipython is not compatible with the newest version of the MKL_intel_thread.dll library. I downgraded and I'm back in business.