# Error installing textblob.download_corpora in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, textblob

I am trying to install and use textblob in my Anaconda environment.  I am following the directions [HERE](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) I am successfully able to pip install `pip install -U textblob`

On step 2 running `python -m textblob.download_corpora` I am presented with multiple errors. One being a Windows popup with the error message:

> the ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   libiomp5md.dll

I am also presented with 2 errors in the terminal:

1. > INTEL MKL ERROR: The operating system cannot run %1.
   >   mkl_intel_thread.dll.
2. > Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Answer (score 0):

look this, you missing a file: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10213

Comment: Thanks for this, it lead me to this link which is what ended up resolving the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026985/the-ordinal-242-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-anaconda3-libra